# Unable to set current user as author of post in Django

Tags: django, django-views, author

I'm trying to set the current logged in user as the author of the post of a form for uploading images. I'm following the advice that can be found in several public questions here in StackOverflow which is: *storing the object coming from form.save() and then assign author value to it*. Unfortunately, it does not seems to work at all for me, and **I keep having no author assigned to the post**. I've checked my code many times but I can't figure out what is wrong.
Can someone please help me with this?

my modes.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager



class Image(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null="true", blank="true")

name = models.TextField(max_length='20')
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", verbose_name='Image', null="true")
secondImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="detail", verbose_name='multiple-image', null="true")

date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
tags = TaggableManager()


@property
def image_url(self):
  if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
    return self.image.url

@property
def secondImage_url(self):
  if self.secondImage and hasattr(self.secondImage, 'url'):
    return self.secondImage.url

def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.post.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)
```

form.py

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import Image


class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        exclude = ('',)
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def upload_Image(request):

if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    raise Http404

ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Image,
                                    form=ImageForm, extra=3)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    images = Image.objects.all()
    common_tags = Image.tags.most_common()[:4]
    if form.is_valid():
        form = Image(file_field=request.FILES['file'])
        newpost = form.save(commit=False)
        newpost.author = request.user
        newpost.slug = slugify(newpost.title)
        newpost.save()

        form.save_m2m()
        context = {
            'images':images,
            'multiple-image':multiple-image,
            'common_tags':common_tags,
            'categories':categories,
            'category':category,
            'form':form,
        }

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/images/')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'photogallery/image_list.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: By uisng `form = Image(file_field=request.FILES['file'])`, you override the `form`.

Answer (score 0):

By writing `form = Image(file_field=request.FILES['file'])` the `form` is no longer the `ImageForm`, but an `Image` object. But nevertheless, it is not a good idea to use the `form.save(commit=False)` method anyway. The form can easily do all the work. Just alter the instance wrapped in the form:

```
@login_required
def upload_Image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.instance.slug = slugify(form.cleaned_data['title'])
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/images/')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'photogallery/image_list.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Willem Van Onsem. I altered the views the way you suggested but I still don't get the author of the posted images.